# What happens when pyridine N-oxide reacts with dichlorocarbene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, heterocyclic-compounds

[image: reaction scheme]

It seems that the combination of sodium methoxide (a base) and chloroform will generate dichlorocarbene, $\ce{CCl2}$, by α-elimination.

What happens after that, though? It is an *ortho* formylation like in the Reimer–Tiemann reaction? Or does the nucleophilic oxygen simply attack the carbene?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dichlorocarbene has been shown to deoxygenate pyridine *N*-oxide producing phosgene as an initial byproduct. In this case, since methoxide is present, dimethyl carbonate is ultimately formed.<sup>[1]</sup>

The proposed mechanism involves nucleophilic attack on the carbene by the oxygen, followed by an elimination:

[image: Mechanism]

(1) Schweizer, E. E.; O'Neill, G. J. A Novel Deoxygenation Method for Pyridine N-Oxide. *J. Org. Chem.* **1963,** *28* (9), 2460–2461. [DOI: 10.1021/jo01044a516](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo01044a516).